# How to change the docker terminal launch script?

Tags: bash, terminal, docker

I would like to change the docker terminal launch script. Where is this located?

I want to add more things to the PATH or define some command aliases.

Comment: Are you talking about the terminal that the Toolbox installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this script?

For mac user
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/osx/mpkg/quickstart.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh

For Windows user:

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/windows/start.sh

The real path in mac is:

```
/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh
```

Comment: Yes, no I found it in the Docker Terminal App contents. Thanks!